# Replicating Unity3D Awake() & Update() methods without Unity

Tags: c#, macos, reflection, mono

Recently I've made the switch from Unity to a bright & shiny OpenGl/Freeglut solution using Mono in Xamarin Studio. I figured this was a wise move because I wasn't learning what I wanted to learn with Unity's handholding. Apparently this wasn't the wisest of moves but I am committed now. There are two things I miss, very much: Awake() & Update().

It was magic. Any object I wanted could extend monobehaviour & I could run some code every frame. But as a neophyte csharper, I'm not entirely sure how to replicate this outside of unity.
Basically I have my main program; the trimmed down version is this:

```
using System;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using OpenGL;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int width = 1280, height = 720;

        public static MyPlayerObj player = new MyPlayerObj();
        public static MyMouseListenerObj mouseE = new MyMouseListenerObj();
        public static MyKeyboardListenerObj keyboardE = new MyKeyboardListenerObj();
        public static MyEnemyObj e1 = new MyEnemyObj();
        public static MyEnemyObj e2 = new MyEnemyObj();
        public static MyEnemyObj e3 = new MyEnemyObj();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Glut.glutInit();
            Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);
            Glut.glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
            Glut.glutCreateWindow("Project");
            Glut.glutIdleFunc(Update);
            Glut.glutDisplayFunc(DisplayFunc);

            Awake();

            Glut.glutMainLoop();
        }

        public static void Awake()
        {
            // Run all Awake Methods
        }

        private static void DisplayFunc()
        {
        } 
        public static void Update()
        {
            Gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            // Run All Update Methods
            // Then run all LateUpdate methods

            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I have some objects such as player, keyboard & mouse listeners, and a bunch of enemies. Now, what I want to do is be able to call each objects Awake method if it has one, or ignore it if it doesn't. This might be something like (pseudocode, forgive me):

```
public static void Update()
{
    interfacedObjects = assembly().findAllObjectsUsingInterface(IUpdateable);
    foreach (var item in interfacedObjects)
    {
        if(item.hasMethod('Update')
            item.call('Update');
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is keep my objects chained to the parent "Monobehaviour". I want to keep my class structure as simple as possible.

```
public class MyPlayerObj : MyMonoBehavior
{
    public void Update()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
public class MyMonoBehavior : IUpdateable
{
    public virtual void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? I know its possible, but I just don't know what this design pattern is called, nor how to execute it.

*I should mention that I would prefer to keep this solution within the native codebase, in the interest of learning.*

Comment: Using glut outside MonoGame sort of defeats the purpose of using MonoGame in the first place.

Comment: That's irrelevant, and incorrect, but thank you for your answer. Sadly, its not relevant to this question.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused when you mentioned MonoGame in your question. Now that you've edited it, the context makes more sense. Glad you found an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

I don't know how Unity does this behind the scenes, but would love to find out. I think the simplest way for you to implement this is to look at the **Observer Design Pattern**. The basic idea that you are looking for is to have a MonoBehavior interface or abstract class that everyone inherits from. Then you  would have a class that handles the MonoBehaviors by running a loop on every MonoBehavior that exists.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. I had previously considered the observer pattern but disregarded it as not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your time. I will experiment and get back to you!

Comment: Actually, I am going to move forward with the Observer pattern; any further questions I have will be derivative of that, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: I wish you best of luck!